# Use a single dockerfile to start many docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, web-deployment

I have a docker image called testapps and this single image has 5 tiny webapps, for now we will call them apps A through E.  I'd like to deploy this single image and create a dockerfile that instantiates a container for each app so that when I run:

```
docker build -t apps .
```

I expect 5 containers and each container is running a different app.

My first question is, how do I reference a locally stored image (saved using command `docker save pesky_perk -o testapps`) in a dockerfile?

Secondly, How do I use the referenced docker image to instantiate 5 containers based off of one image, each with it's own Entry point like:

```
#Container 1
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/A.jar"]
#Container 2
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/B.jar"]
#Container 3
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/C.jar"]
#Container 4
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/D.jar"]
#Container 5
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/E.jar"]
```

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Dockerfile doesn't instantiate containers. It just builds images. If you want to use the same image to run multiple apps, just include the relevant commands on the `docker run` command line:

```
docker run --name app_A myimage /A.jar
docker run --name app_B myimage /B.jar
docker run --name app_C myimage /C.jar
docker run --name app_D myimage /D.jar
docker run --name app_E myimage /E.jar
```

This assumes your Dockerfile contains:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar"]
```

---

The `FROM` line in a Dockerfile *always* refers to a local image: if it doesn't exist locally, it is pulled from a remote repository. But if it matches an available local image, you're all set.

If you have the output of `docker save`, you would need to `docker load` it first so that your local Docker daemon was aware of it.

Comment: What if the dockerfile  DOES NOT contain ENTRYPOINT["java", "-jar"]?

Comment: In that case, those command lines would fail, because they would try to run the command `/A.jar`, which probably isn't runnable by itself.

Comment: Then you should specify the whole command :

`docker run --name app_A myimage java -jar /A.jar`